# Why are NoSQL equivalents of MySQL joins so much more expensive than SQL ones?

Tags: database, join, nosql

Could someone get into the technicals as to why NoSQL equivalents of MySQL joins are so much more expensive than SQL ones?

Comment: What do you mean by joins? For example MongoDB doesn't even have joins. You need to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it is more expensive.

Joins in a non-distributed system are straightforward. The data's on the same server, and you simply go and find it.

In a distributed system - which just about every NoSQL is - the data might be local, or it might be remote. You have to do at least a calculation to determine the location of the data, then get the data from the other servers.

It is a hard problem (maybe even a fool's errand) to optimize the cluster so associated data is on the "same server" - because what is "associated" changes. Some distributed NoSQL databases, such as my companies' Aerospike database, make a point of randomly distributing data so joins are all equal cost - even if slower. Some cases - like small, well known tables with commonly read and infrequently written data - can be implemented on every server easily, but few NoSQL allow that (currently).

To create a comparison, you'll have to create a distributed SQL cluster, using your favorite distributed SQL technology (such as MySQL Cluster), and compare client join patterns vs the overhead of SQL parsing, optimizer runs, and then fetching from different parts of the cluster.

I've never seen such a benchmark. Most NoSQL use patterns eschew the normalize-and-join SQL patterns, so it is not well tested.